# Tkinter Scrollbar not working due to textbox size

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to bound the text box within the window size. But here in my code, the text box exceeds the window size vertically and that is why scrollbar is not working (as far as I have observed). Also the scrollbar is attached with the frame instead of text box. I want it to be attached with the text box.

```
from tkinter import *

class myGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Result')
        self.root.geometry('400x400+580+120')
        self.root.configure(bg = 'azure2')
        self.root.focus()

        frame_1 = Frame(self.root, bg = 'red')
        frame_1.pack()

        Label(frame_1, 
            text = f"On 08/09/12, following students were absent.",
            font = ("",'10','bold'),
            bg = 'azure2').pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

        textbox = Text(frame_1, width = 40, height = 20, state = DISABLED, cursor = 'arrow')
        textbox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)

        for i in range(1, 50):
            abs_std = Label(textbox, text = f'Student Name {i}', bg = 'white').pack(padx = 10, anchor = 'w')
            textbox.window_create('end', window = abs_std)
            textbox.insert('end', '\n')

        vsb_1 = Scrollbar(frame_1, orient = VERTICAL, command = textbox.yview)
        vsb_1.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

        textbox.config(yscrollcommand = vsb_1.set)

        close_Button = Button(self.root,
                        text = 'CLOSE',
                        font = 'TkDefaultFont 9 bold',
                        bg = 'dark turquoise',
                        command = self.root.destroy)
        close_Button.pack(pady = 20, ipadx = 4)

b = myGUI()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you inserting labels instead of just adding text to the `Text` widget?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the following line:

```
abs_std = Label(textbox, text = f'Student Name {i}', bg = 'white').pack(padx = 10, anchor = 'w')
```

`pack(...)` is used to insert the label into `textbox` and also causes `abs_std` to be  `None`.

Remove the `pack(...)`.

Also you created the `textbox` with `state=DISABLED`, so the line `textbox.insert('end', '\n')` will not work.  Create the `textbox` with normal state and set it to disabled after inserting the labels:

```
    textbox = Text(frame_1, width = 40, height = 20, state = NORMAL, cursor = 'arrow')
    textbox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)

    for i in range(1, 50):
        abs_std = Label(textbox, text = f'Student Name {i}', bg = 'white')
        textbox.window_create('end', window = abs_std)
        textbox.insert('end', '\n')
    textbox.config(state=DISABLED)
```